# Openstack: how to get client's IP in the python API

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I'm trying to implement a new weigher for cells on openstack. How can I get the client IP (the user who is requesting to create a new instance) inside openstack nova python code?

I already have tried

req.remote_addr

inside files nova/api/auth.py (NovaKeystoneContext.**call** method) and nova/api/compute_req_id.py (ComputeReqIdMiddleware method), but without success. LOG.debug seems to indicate those methods are not called when a new instance creation is requested.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might be interested, I found a solution.

When you create a new weighter you will need to add a method like this:

```
def _weigh_object(self, cell, weight_properties):
```

To obtain the client's IP you just need to call

```
weight_properties['context'].remote_address
```

One last details: you will need to restart nova services for that change take place:

```
service nova-cells restart (as root)
```